# See modified media in KMC or via Kaltura api?

Tags: php, diff, kaltura

Is there a way to get the media which was modified after it was created ?
In other words, is there a flag or a field for lastupdate or lastmodification ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no flag for telling if an entry has been updated, but there is a field that keep the timestamp of last update in "updatedAt". 
you can filter entries by "updatedAtGreaterThanOrEqual" or "updatedAtLessThanOrEqual" by list action through Kaltura api.